# Exim rejected RCPT

Tags: email, dovecot, exim

Recently I changed the router on the network, opened all the ports up and got it working
Not long after making this change mail on the server stopped working.

The mail log is returning this message:

"rejected RCPT"

```
2014-10-09 21:15:04 H=edge.infinitysrv.com [198.91.80.248] F=<info@oliverwhysall.co.uk> rejected RCPT <info@edithshouse.com>
```

Just a straight rejected RCPT

What should I be looking for to solve this issue?

I have telneted into mail.edithshouse.com and when running `mail <>` it returns okay, then `"rctp to: info@oliverwhysall.co.uk"` it returns the message:

```
550 Administrative prohibition
```

server in question is http://edithshouse.com

Comment: Whether your DNS records are correct? Is your server is configured as an open relay? Whether it is in black list?

Comment: Hi Kondybas, Server isn't blacklisted currently - DNS all checks out. Its not currently set as an open relay, but can open if needed.

Answer (score 1):

DNSstuff reports

`Could not connect: Got an unknown RCPT TO response: 550 Administrative prohibition`

for the email address `info@edithshouse.com`, so it's not you. Either send your email to a known valid email address at that domain or contact the intended recipient and ask them to speak to their email administrator.